# Should mental health questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

It could be argued that mental health is such a big subject in its own right that this site should not accept such questions and should stick to physical health.  Should we accept mental health questions or not?

Comment: Related: [Merge `Mental Health` into `Health`](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/19261/61861)

Comment: How about reconsidering which answer to accept?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt why?

Comment: The accepted answer used to be a different one

Comment: so mental health questions are officially on topic then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the comments to the other answer I propose: mental health questions are **on-topic** for the following reasons:

- mental health is part of global health
- in some cases, it's difficult to draw a line between the two areas
- there are several interactions between psychological processes and physical-organic phenomena

Comment: What answer are you referring to?

Comment: so mental health questions are officially on topic then?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I find mental health things like psychopathy or narcissism very interesting topics.

So I would vote to include these type of questions.

On the other hand, there is already [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: so mental health questions are officially on topic then?

Answer (score -6):

No, this site was was created on the premise of serving [medical health](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048?phase=definition). There is nothing in the proposal suggesting this extend into physiological or mental health issues, and we did not solicit support from that community. That is simply a different scope of expertise … well, not exactly "simply" — it's a complicated issue — but this site should focus primarily on issues of *physical* health.

Comment: How are you distinguishing medical health from physiological health?

Comment: I'm not (that's what my last sentence was about). We can say that this site isn't about mental health, and stick to the physical — but there's a fuzzy middle ground where body and brain chemistry crosses into purely psychological health issue that we'll have to explore when it comes up in actual practice. For now, I'm just saying that the field of "mental health" is not really what this site was intended for.

Comment: I think at times issues in one area can cause issues in the other so it would be hard to separate the areas

Comment: @JoeW e.g. psychoneuroimmunology. Hard to draw a line indeed, if one wants to draw one.

Comment: Sorry to be the typo police, but I think this is actually confusing people - do you mean “psychological” (or perhaps “psychiatric”) rather than “physiological”? The latter refers to that which pertains to normal functions of any part of the body (as distinguished from pathophysiologic(al) - abnormal functioning). Physiology is not specific to the brain or mental health, and I think we would all agree that it’s on topic here.

Comment: so mental health questions are officially on topic then?