# Can we clean up the tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

I would really like to [organize tags](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/165) but agree with [one answer on another meta question about tag management](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/183/165) that this is going to take some leadership from high-rep users to maintain. I think that would be a great way to keep these folks invested by making useful edits to newbie questions, but it would probably be best implemented after we have pro tempore moderators in place to head it up.

In the meantime, there are a bunch of synonyms and a bunch of tags with questionable utility that really could use some tidying. Apparently one needs 1250 rep to suggest synonyms, so I’m asking for help.

**Synonyms**: 
 In each case, I advocate for the first tag remaining and the one(s) following being made synonyms:

- [tendinitis](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendinitis), [tendinopathy](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendinopathy), [tendon](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendon) 
   Technically not synonyms, but we really only need one tag.
- [cardiology](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardiology), [cardio](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardio), [cardiac](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardiac) 
   The first is my preference but doesn’t exist.
- [infection](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infection), [germs](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germs)
- [musculoskeletal-system](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musculoskeletal-system), [muscle](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle)
- [radiation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation), [radiations](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiations), [scanning](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scanning) 
  First doesn’t exist.
- [sleep-deprivation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep-deprivation), [sleep-deprive](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep-deprive) 
   First doesn’t exist.
- [treatment-options](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment-options), [treatment](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment) 
   Maybe these fall into the category below?
- [pulmonology](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pulmonology), [breathing](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breathing)
- [pharmacology](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacology), [drugs](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drugs)
- [dermatology](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dermatology), [skin](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skin)

**Tags that don’t make much sense to me**: 
These aren’t [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) as traditionally defined, but they are tags that apply to an ill-defined and potentially unrelated set of questions (e.g. [removal](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removal)) or could be applied to just about any question (e.g. [body](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body), [effects](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects)).

- [body](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body), [detrimental](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/detrimental), [effects](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects), [disease](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disease), [removal](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removal), [treatment](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment)

Please use answer space to give feedback about these ideas and/or to report on any piece of this you’d like to undertake.

Comment: Unfortunately, only 1250+ users can do the tag synonyms. We also need to vet them for spelling, as tendnitis shows in your first example.

Comment: @JohnP Thanks, that was actually my typo, not the tagger’s. Oops. Fixed.

Comment: We need to be careful when making them to ensure that the tag that covers the most topics is what is linked to.

Comment: There is also diabetes and type 1 diabetes, you should use he tag management tag for this post as well.

Comment: @dustin Good point, I added [tag:tag-management].

Comment: @dustin - I edited that tag, it was originally t1dm. I think we probably need one tag for each type, as each one may have questions specific to themselves.

Comment: @JohnP May I suggest [tag:diabetes-type-1] and [tag:diabetes-type-2] so that when one starts typing they both come up as options?

Comment: Absolutely. Good point.'

Comment: @JohnP then [tag:diabetes] seems irrelevant since the diabetes type can be specified.

Comment: @dustin - Mmm...I think there will still be questions about diabetes in general rather than specific.

Comment: 1250+... you'll be able to do that tomorrow :)