# "Happy marriage" question and topicality

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

This question was closed by myself and one other community member:

https://health.stackexchange.com/q/5505/165

The OP has edited and requested re-opening. To me, the question remains primarily focused on an outcome that is more the subject of sociology than health. However, it's true that the mental health field (which I agree [is on topic](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/61/165)) deals with research endpoints in various domains of "quality of life", into which this could, I suppose, fall.

In my opinion this veers too far afield from *health* proper.* However, particularly since it was closed by a moderator with only one community vote, I don't want to leave it closed against community opinion.

Is this question on topic?

---

<sub>*The other objection raised was "primarily opinion based" which the title most certainly is, but with regard to the essence of the question this is not an insurmountable barrier to re-opening in my opinion. (See "research endpoints in various domains of quality of life" above; see also [my prior objections to "opinion-based"](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/227/165).)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the question has fundamentally changed. The OP says he can't find any research on the subject and then asks if any exists. So, basically, it's a "*do my research for me*" question, which I consider off-topic on virtually all SE forums.

The trouble with such questions is it's impossible to prove that no research on a subject exists, so the question can only be answered by actually doing a literature search and coming up with positive results. That's not a useful question; it's just a reassignment of work.

I think such questions should be closed here for lack of research as they are on many other SE forums.

Answer (score -1):

The question claims that a high libido might be an addiction (disease), and is asking how that might affect someone's relationships.  So, this might come under the on topic category

> The ways that diseases and injuries affect people

Certainly there's marriage research to suggest mismatched libido is a cause of marital discord and breakup, but it might more properly come under health psychology. Certainly a GP might be asked something like this, and if mathematics is what mathematicians do, and health is what doctors concern themselves with, then it would be on topic.